# Change the configuration location of vsftpd?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, init

How do I change the configuration location of vsftpd? It is currently in a file directly off /etc and I'd like it to be in /etc/vsftpd/ so that I can include some other stuff in there and not clutter up /etc while I'm at it. It also makes configuration management a bit easier as I'm considering a cluster of these.

Comment: OS: I'm dealing with 14.04 Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of `vsftpd` can be specified as a command-line parameter. To do so, you'll need to [override the default command](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files) in `/etc/init/vsftpd.conf` (assuming you're not on 15.04 or later):

```
printf "exec /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf\n" | 
  sudo tee -a /etc/init/vsftpd.override
```

Now restart `vsftpd` and it should pick up the new location.

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: @A.B. Mistakes happen, that's ok, don't mention it. Why did you delete your answer, though?

Comment: My answer does not make sense when the solution is so simple.